# How to solve modules which use overrides are not able to install / uninstall properly in prestshop

Tags: php, prestashop

I have createsd a new module in prestashop. Here I had overrite some core functionality of product class.

My overrite file has placed in the location :  `prestashop/modules/mymodule/override/`

When I install the module i am getting the following Error :

```
 Cannot redeclare class ProductOverrideOriginal in /var/www/html/htdocs/prestashop/modules/sharesoft_relatedproducts/sharesoft_relatedproducts.php(96) : eval()'d code on line 2
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module sharesoft_relatedproducts.php(96) : eval()'d :
Cannot redeclare class ProductOverrideOriginal .
```

How can i fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means jsut what it says. Your code tries to declare a class twice (with the same), so there is a conflict.

I also do not understand why your class is named `ProductOverrideOriginal`. All Prestashop overrides must override original PrestaShop classes, for example

```
class Product extends ProductCore { ...
```

From the error message I presume that you tried to include your overriden class

```
require('/override/sharesoft_relatedproducts.php');
```

But all files from module folder

```
prestashop/modules/mymodule/override/
```

are automatically copied to

```
prestashop/override/
```

during module installation. My guess is that your override class file is copied there, and is loaded, but you also try to include it again in your module, which gives you error (trying to declare twice).

Also, make sure you use statements like:

```
require_once('myfile.php');
```

or

```
if (!class_exists('MyFile'))
    require_once('myfile.php');
```

to ensure that the same class is not declared twice. Seconde option is better because its faster (does not check file system)

Comment: where to write the code either install or construct

Comment: You dont need to include or require your overriden classes, because they are copied and used automatically by PS.

Comment: Or just paste your code to pastebin or first line so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-make-an-override-in-your-module.html please refer the link .I used the same function for install overrides

Comment: You only need to manually install overrides with this functions if PrestaShop is 1.4 or lower. Versions 1.5 and 1.6 install it automatically.